# TypeError: Cannont Read Property `State` of Undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Getting the error :

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

I face this error when i am going to get my input state value by event `onSubmit()` .

```
onFormSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.term);
}
```

Comment: In your constructor, add `this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);`.

Comment: or change your function to `onFormSubmit = (event) =>`

Comment: bind your onFormSubmit `this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);`

Comment: Always remember this: You need to bind your function in the constructor before calling it.

Comment: Searching for the error results in lots of existing questions.

Comment: Thanks @ChrisG It's working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use arrow function instead so:

Change

```
onFormSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.term);
}
```

To

```
onFormSubmit= (event)=>{
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(this.state.term);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont have context (`this` is not bound to your function).

You can fix that using one of the following:

First, bind this in constructor

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.onFormSubmit = this.onFormSubmit.bind(this);
}
```

Second, use arrow functions

```
onFormSubmit = (event) => {
  ...
}
```

Third, use [autobind-decorator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/autobind-decorator) or the like

```
@boundMethod
onFormSubmit(event) {
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use arrow function Like :

```
onFormSubmit = (event) =>{
  event.preventDefault();
  console.log(this.state.term);
}
```