# Cannot read property 'setState' of undefined, when running a function

Tags: reactjs

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      sideNav: '',
      language: 'en'
    }
  }

  langEn() {
    this.setState({language: 'en'}).bind(this);
    console.log("Language changed to en");
  }

  langEs() {
    this.setState({language: 'es'}).bind(this);
    console.log("Language changed to es");
  }

  render() {

    const mouseEnter = e => {
      this.setState({sideNav: "sideNav sidenav---sidenav---_2tBP sidenav---expanded---1KdUL"});
    }    

    const mouseLeave = e => {
      this.setState({sideNav: "sidenav---sidenav---_2tBP sidenav---collapsed---LQDEv"});
    }


    return (
      <div className="App container">
        <div>
          <SideNav 
            onMouseEnter={mouseEnter} 
            onMouseLeave={mouseLeave}
            className={this.state.sideNav}
            onSelect={(selected) => {
                // Add your code here
            }}
          >
            <SideNav.Nav  defaultSelected="home">
                <NavItem eventKey="home">
                    <NavIcon>
                        <Link to="/"><img src={Dash}/></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/">Dashboard</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="sites">
                    <NavIcon>
                      <Link to="/sites"><img src={Site} /></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/sites">Sites</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="tours">
                  <NavIcon>
                    <Link to="/tours"><img src={Tour}/></Link>
                  </NavIcon>
                  <NavText>
                      <Link to="/tours">Tours</Link>
                  </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="media">
                    <NavIcon>
                      <Link to="/media"><img src={Media}/> </Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/media">Media</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="newSite">
                    <NavIcon>
                        <Link to="/newSite/details"><img src={NewSite} /></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/newSite/details">Add new Site</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="language">
                    <NavIcon>
                        <Link to="/language"><img src={Lang} /></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/language">Language</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>
                <NavItem eventKey="profile">
                    <NavIcon>
                        <Link to="/profile"><img src={Profile} /></Link>
                    </NavIcon>
                    <NavText>
                        <Link to="/profile">Profile</Link>
                    </NavText>
                </NavItem>

            </SideNav.Nav>
            <button onClick={this.langEn}>EN</button>
            <button onClick={this.langEs}>ES</button>
          </SideNav>
        </div>
        <Routes childProps={this.state} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

The error happens when I press one of the two buttons to run the lanEn or lanEs functions. I have tried alternating where they are, placing them in or out of the `render()` method, removing `this` using bind. The end goal is change the language state using these buttons and transfer it to different pages using props

Comment: Try using arrow functions instead. Check out this answer from about an hour ago https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54982653/typeerror-cannont-read-property-state-of-undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to add this piece of code in the constructor:

```
this.langEn = this.langEn.bind(this);
```

What the above code does is, it replaces the existing `langEn` function with a new function with the `this` context changed to `class App`.

If you don't want to manually bind it in the constructor, you can go with arrow functions, which has lexical binding.

Comment: It's working now but I have a way of sending `this.state.language` to my Routes as a prop, but when I press the button to update the state, it doesn't update the route too

Comment: @TiernO In you current example, the code for setting language state is harcoded to have `en` as the value always: `this.setState({language: 'en'}).bind(this);`. Whenever the state changes, it will reset to the same value. That is the reason, it's not updating in prop as well.

Comment: Oh I understand, so how do i fix it?

Comment: @TiernO also, `setState` doesn't return anything. So having the bind statement  like `this.setState({language: 'en'}).bind(this);` may result in an exception since you're trying to bind something which is undefined. You only need `this.setState({language: 'en'})` for setting the state.

Comment: Yes i have removed the bind() from the setState call

Comment: @TiernO I just noticed that you have another function for setting `es` as the language. Clicking on that button should make it work as long as the code doesn't break. Please check the console if you have any errors.

Comment: @Tierno You need to bind the function for `es` as well `this.langEs = this.langEs.bind(this);` in the constructor.

Comment: Yes I did that and it is working. my props still doesnt change

Answer (score 0):

First, you try to bind `this.setState` in `langEn` and `langEn`. Why?

Second, all this stuff happens because functions have their own context.

Whether use bind for methods call:

```js
...
<button onClick={this.langEn.bind(this)}>EN</button>
...
```

or use arrow key functions (they have no their own context):

```js
langEn = () => {
  this.setState({language: 'es'}, () => console.log("Language changed to es"));
}
```

Comment: When I use the bind I get an error saying "Cannot  read property "bind" of undefined"

Comment: @TiernO you should bind not on this.setState, but on the function calling (e.g, `langEn`). Look the code above.

Comment: You get the error because you try to bind the undefined method `setState` of the current function context.

Answer (score 0):

Just simply bind methods in the constructor:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = {
      sideNav: '',
      language: 'en'
    }
    this.langEn.bind(this);
    this.langEs.bind(this);
  }

  langEn() {
    this.setState({language: 'en'}).bind(this);
    console.log("Language changed to en");
  }

  langEs() {
    this.setState({language: 'es'}).bind(this);
    console.log("Language changed to es");
  }

  render() {

    const mouseEnter = e => {
      this.setState({sideNav: "sideNav sidenav---sidenav---_2tBP sidenav---expanded---1KdUL"});
    }    

    const mouseLeave = e => {
      this.setState({sideNav: "sidenav---sidenav---_2tBP sidenav---collapsed---LQDEv"});
    }


    return (
      <div className="App container">
...
      <button onClick={this.langEn}>EN</button>
      <button onClick={this.langEs}>ES</button>
...
```